# Configuring a valid service endpoint

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory

According to [Configuring the Artifactory Service Endpoint](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Azure+DevOps#AzureDevOps-ConfiguringtheArtifactoryServiceEndpoint), an artifactory instance as service endpoint need to be configured. One of the parameter is the server URL to the artifactory. What if the server URL is a local intranet, will the URL be considered valid ? I am having error with the URL I am providing (Local intranet). The error is:

> "Failed to query service connection.....Error Message:'An error
>   occurred while sending the request'"

Comment: Are you using an on prem or the SaaS Azure DevOps service? If it is the later, surely it won't be able to access your local (private) network.

Comment: I think Azure Devops is SaaS. What are the options then to push artifacts to local intranet artifactory via Azure Devops Pipeline Task?

Comment: You can use self hosted agents, installed within your network. You can read more about it on Azure DevOps documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> What if the server URL is a local intranet, will the URL be
>   considered valid ?

While the server URL you used here is a local internet, which means our azure image(`Hosted agent`) could not get communicate with it from public internet. That's why the error message told you failed to send request to server.

So, here the best way is you need configure one [self agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) in that local machine.

**BUT**, if `Hosted agent` is one preferred choice in pipeline execution. I'm afraid you have to configure your artifactory instance to make it accessible from the internet, just like the URL in the blog you shared above. Because our Hosted agent actually is Azure VM which hosted in cloud.

Comment: Have already got a self-hosted build agent that run behind proxy. Cannot even verify the URL - https://jfrog.bintray.com/jfrog-cli-go/

Comment: @sajis997, does this URL is what you are connecting now? Because I saw it start with  `https`. Are you using TFS or azure devops service? Any error message occurred when you trying to connect to this URL? Error message is more clear for me to know what exactly wrong here.